# Retrieve List of Tables in MS Access File

Tags: c#, .net, database, ms-access, metadata

If I can open a connection to an MS Access file in C#, how can I retrieve a list of the different tables that exist in the Access DB (and if possible, any meta-data associated with the tables)?

Comment: What metadata are you in need of knowing about?

Comment: At the very least, the description of the table (if one is saved)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of tables in an Access (Jet) database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152545/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-tables-in-an-access-jet-database)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I just found the following solution from [David Hayden](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/10/01/GetListOfTablesInMicrosoftAccessUsingGetSchema.aspx)

```
// Microsoft Access provider factory
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");

DataTable userTables = null;
using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection()) {
  // c:\test\test.mdb
  connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\\test\\test.mdb";
  // We only want user tables, not system tables
  string[] restrictions = new string[4];
  restrictions[3] = "Table";

  connection.Open();

  // Get list of user tables
  userTables = connection.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions);
}

List<string> tableNames = new List<string>();
for (int i=0; i < userTables.Rows.Count; i++)
    tableNames.Add(userTables.Rows[i][2].ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. C# WPF Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 0):

Here's are some links:

- [Displaying Tables of An Access Database Through C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/2a2910b7-97f4-4634-9aba-114cd87af89d)
- [Walkthrough: Editing an Access Database with ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971485.aspx)

Here's a VB.NET snipit to get all the columns of a Access Table, I know it's not exactly what you're looking for, but a similar primciple apples when listing all the tables:

```
Dim oleConn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & myDB & ";User Id=admin;Password=;")

oleConn.Open()
Dim schemaTable As DataTable
Dim i As Integer
schemaTable = oleConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Column s, _
New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, "tblTheTableToListColumns", Nothing})
For i = 0 To schemaTable.Columns.Count - 1
Debug.Print(schemaTable.Rows(i)!COLUMN_NAME.ToStri ng)
Next i
oleConn.Close()
```