# Connect to mdb without knowing the cols?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, mdb2

I have a mdb file with a lot of data.
I don't know the names of the tables or the cols inside.
I need to build a c# app that will show some details on this db. What is the options to view the starcture of the tables? I tried use some mdb viewers but the file is too big for that. 
I just need the names of the tables and not the values.

Comment: This question has already been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699897/retrieve-list-of-tables-in-ms-access-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call the get OleDbSchemaTable method on the OleDbConnection object, i haven't used this before but the equivilent functionality on the SqlConnection object can provide extensive information on the database schema.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getoledbschematable(v=vs.71).aspx][1]